# specify through type signature that an object has a property of a given type

Tags: typescript

Background: I'm writing a simple sorting function to sort objects in order of the value of a given property (basically the same as Lodash's "sortBy"). I want to make sure each object is of the same overall type, and that the given property is `string | number`, and that it matches on both objects (i.e. they can both be string, or both be number, but they both need to be the same). I feel like I should be able to do this just with the type signatures that I give my arguments, but I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

Here's what I've got so far:

```js
compareObjectsForSorting(a: object, b: object, propertyName: string, sortDescending = false): number {
  /* First, some safety checks to make sure the arguments match what's intended.
  Check that the desired property is even present on both objects, and throw an error if not */
  [a, b].forEach((obj) => {
    if (!Object.keys(obj).includes(propertyName)) {
      throw new Error(propertyName + 'not found in object' + obj);
    }
  });
  /* Let's just stick to comparing numbers and strings */
  const typeOfPropA = typeof a[propertyName];
  const typeOfPropB = typeof b[propertyName];
  [typeOfPropA, typeOfPropB].forEach((t) => {
    if (t !== 'string' && t !== 'number') {
      throw new Error(`${propertyName} is of type ${t}. Please compare only strings or numbers.`);
    }
  });
  /* And finally, let's make sure the same property is of the same type in both objects */
  if (typeOfPropA !== typeOfPropB) {
    throw new Error(`Unable to compare. ${propertyName} is a ${typeof a[propertyName]} 
    in one object, and a ${typeof b[propertyName]} in another.`);
  }
  // ... and then comes the actual logic of comparing, not shown here.
}
```

I know that I could use type parameters to define both objects as `<T>`, and then I wouldn't have to check that they match. But how do I say that `<T>` needs one property to be `string | number`, and that the key of that property is determined by argument `propertyName`?

Or am I just getting too ambitious?

Comment: Doing the above doesn't make any sense to me: (1) either enforce the type to be the same or ignore it in the comparison. (2) a sorting function in TS/JS accepts only two arguments, yours accepting four. (3) It's unclear where you want to apply generics and to what exactly?

Comment: @NirAlfasi Thanks; 1) "enforce the type" is exactly what I'm trying for; 2) this function will be called *inside* the callback of Array.sort, with extra arguments supplied by scope (e.g. `fooArray.sort((a, b) => compareForSorting(a, b, this.sortPropertyKey, this.sortOrder`); 3) I'm afraid I don't understand the question, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea for sure, you should be able to do this just with types if you don't want to need to have runtime validation.

I think the core thing to look at is the bounds for generics that you can specify using the `extends` keyword. So `const f = <T extends string>(a:T)=>{}` will only accept strings for argument `a`. `const f = <T extends string|number>(a:T)=>{}` will accept strings or numbers. And if you are looking to specify a generic which should be an object with values of type string or number you can extends off of `Record<string, string | number>` or `Record<PropertyKey,string|number>` to have the keys as `string | number | symbol` which I guess the default object keys are expected to be in js.

Then if you want to accept multiple objects you could have an array of the generic as the argument type, so the signature for the function might look like.

```
const sort = <T extends Record<string, string | number>>(
  objects: readonly T[],
  property: keyof T,
) => {};
```

Here `property` argument is typed as `keyof T` which creates the expected constraint for the key to exist on the objects.

This works okay, as it enforces that the property should exist on the generic `T` so theses cases are checked correctly

```
sort([{ a: 5 }, { a: "a" }], "a"); //ok
sort([{ a: 5 }, { a: "a" }], "b"); //argument of type '"b"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a"'
```

But in the case that the objects passed in have different keys, the generic is resolved as `Record<string, string | number>` which is correct but not specific enough and any string is assignable to type `string` so the property is not checked

```
sort([{ a: 5 }, { b: "a" }], "a"); //ok
```

So if all objects should have property, the property can be made generic instead, and the objects array argument can be built using that generic as the key. So like

```
const sort = <K extends PropertyKey>(
  objects: readonly Record<K, string | number>[],
  property: K,
) => {};
```

And whatever test cases we had before should work

```
sort([{ a: 5 }, { a: "a" }], "a"); //ok
sort([{ a: 5 }, { a: "a" }], "b"); //argument of type '"b"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a"'
sort([{ a: 5 }, { b: "a" }], "a"); //Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'b' does not exist in type 'Record<"a", string | number>'
```

Link to [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBICdYF4YB4DSMCmAPK2YAJhDAAoIgAO2SAnhtnQHwAUAsAFAwwgBGAK2zAoEAFwwE2AIZFwAGzowASsMRFMAGjhQEASzABzGAB8YYAK4BbPrWYBtALqauPKpRr0JGF5wCUMMjMMADeAL4A3Fxc8Eis9iEw0hIArDBh2onJMABE0jnpzrn5fhEwAPTlIADWMYhQ8Vmp6ZlJEnkFYUU5fDmlFeXSCIbWhLAgAGYwUHQ0MADkPTnzMHqkYCCw0hAQeoZg0nzy2NMgMFRD0lbYBAi8UzNzi-nzdXEJbTBpGaEwfO35QraDr9SoAeUEwlg8j0t2k8hgVmkSgUSggNGAegmSmqGwA7mBzh5aFA9NgINppMQFnwVnJyeZNjhcGtYAZprMTvNVKAEBoOtpoPojKZzNZbAhmK9OFwgA)

If you want all objects to have the same type for each property, and we assume the first object to be input should be the one from which types are derived, you can update the function to be

```
const sort = <K extends PropertyKey, T1 extends Record<K,unknown>, T2 extends T1>(
  objects: [T1, ...T2[]],
  property: K,
) => {};
```

Here T1 is the generic that should be the object with the correct types, or this ones to expected on the following objects. T2 must extend T1, so this is kind of the constraint, and can be approximately thought of as T2 should be pretty much the same as T1, but we need it as another type or T1 would just be widened with union etc... like string | number instead of just either of them. Then objects array is created from that, I think its a tuple really as far as typescript is concerned, but the length is variable as 1 (T1) + however many T2.

Also, can notice we use generic `K` to constrain the keys in `T1` generic, which in turn get carried onto `T2`.

Here is a link to updated [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBICdYF4YB4DSMCmAPK2YAJhDAAoIgAO2SAnhtnQDQwAqAjDvoSTAErZQCIpmbQEASzABzAD5gArgFsARrQB8rNgCZuBYqU4aAFAFgAUDBghVAKyFQIALhgBtTqwB0P3W4C6-syW1lSUNPSuGMEWAJQwyBowAN4AvgDclpbwSCZuyTAAhq4ArDCprAXFMABEhTXlQbX1sekwAPTtYCCwIADW2YhQeVWl5ZVFrnUNqU01qjWtHe2FCDIqhL0AZjBQdDQwAOTzNYcwkqTdsIUQEJIyYIWqADbYuyAwVKuFytgECDYdnsDsd6odBrl8pMYGUKikYKopvVGqxpktOgB5eyOGDPST-QrPGDKQp0GxgZ5kiA0YCSLZkvrdADuYE%204VoUEk2AgrEKxCOqjORBA3JgV24F1g0l2%20zeh0EwlE01YEmkMhgcjFKnUCA04IsOWGUOqsIm1QAbCjmotlv0gA)

Comment: Notice that in their 3rd runtime check, OP tests for equality of type of the values, whereas your 1st sample accepts different types.

Comment: Yea, I just wrote out the thought process I think makes it most intuitive to understand. Through the first solution which has that issue, and then the next iteration which switches generics and should work for desired outcome. I think it's clear enough but edit if you think can be clearer.

Comment: This is awesome and I just learned some new things. But it misses one of my use cases: I want `sort([{ a: 5 }, { a: "a" }], "a")` *not* to be ok. I want to enforce "the specified property can be either string or number, but it must be the same type on both objects." I wonder whether I can figure it out from this much... thinking...

Comment: yea if you want to do that it's a little more involved, you  can express a generic as the first item in the array, and then a second type that should extend that type and then objects arg can be created by spread an array of the second with the first as the first item in the array type.

Comment: I can update to show how could be done

Comment: Thanks for the update! Before checking back here I also realized I could just do `objects: readonly Record<K, string>[] | Record<K, number>[]`; that way all objects within the array are equal in type, and K can be either string or number, but it has to stick with one or the other.

Comment: yea for sure no problem. Yes that works too, they mean different things, whatever your use case can chose whatever is best. Having explicit key types will constrain all value types of the object to be the same, if you bind the constraint to a generic even an object with mixed values can be used as an argument.